# Margins wont work with auto tag on image

Tags: html, css, margin

Trying to center an image.

Using the `margin-left: auto;` and `margin-right: auto;` tags does not work.

Below is my implementation 
What am I doing wrong / what do I need to add

```
<style>
.fix{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    width: 30%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
 }
</style>

<img src="DigitalBannerwithX.png" width="40%" height="auto" class="fix" onclick="this.style.display = 'none'" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `position: fixed;` you should use the corresponding `left` and `right` to position it center (margin would work too, but each should be a percentage that adds up to 100% with the width). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGjybG

Answer (score -2):

you can try this one:

```
                  .fix{
position:fixed;
bottom:0px;
width: 30%;
margin-left:50%;
margin-right: 50%;
background-color:red;

}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/xavprgr7/1/)

Comment: This will not be in the center. Add a background color to your image to see where you've placed it. The margin left and right would need to be equal to 35%.

Comment: yes, this solution is wrong. You place it to 50% from right, so if the item is 30 % width, then it leaves 20% screen width right of it, and 50% left...

Comment: sure it looks like centered! making your image fit 30% of the screen leaves 70% for margins. Then dispatch these right and left (35%) and you get your "magic fix" but this implies that your image will always be 30% of width, whatever its real resolution is. So, to me, this is not a "real" solution neither :/

Comment: Should't the image always be at 30% width then? @Julo0sS

Comment: if your image "real" width is 100px, then if you display your "app" on a wide screen like 1920px, if your image there takes 30% width, so 640px instead of 100px, what would it look like? pixels are great aren't they? :P What you need is to keep image original size and center it.

Comment: Without setting a width on the image, you can use left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); but restraining the width of the image to 30% is fine to do too.

Comment: this is weird, did you think about just placing a container at the bottom of the page, with a fixed bottom 0 attribute and then place your image, without setting any size attribute into it, with margin 0 auto and text-align center for container? @user3764684

Comment: @Julo0sS nope! I will keep that in mind for the future. thank you